# How to parameterize the Cookies in Karate API?

Tags: karate

Today we have tried below code in our local machines, we keep on getting error really its too hectic.

Problem: We are unable to parameterize cookies for request using karate.

Brief details:

We just called java method where it will return Map as object, those map object values we wanted to place it in request cookies level.

Code snippet:

- def loginSecurity = Java.type('com.XXXXXXX.apis.BaseAPI')
- def token = loginSecurity.apiAuthentication() //  here apiAuthentication is the method and it will return Java map object
- print 'Token values are: ' +token.get("JSESSIONID") // Printing map values working fine

Given path '/XXXX/base/services/user/companies'
And cookies = {JSESSIONID: token.get("JSESSIONID"),  AWSELB: token.get("AWSELB"), ETag:token.get("ETag")}
And header Content-Type = 'application/json' 
When method GET
* print respoonse

When I run above code, getting error at cookies initialization from Map. Please help here how to pass the parameterize the values into cookies

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually read the documentation. Then things will be less "hectic": https://github.com/intuit/karate#embedded-expressions

```
And cookies = { JSESSIONID: '#(token.JSESSIONID)',  AWSELB: '#(token.AWSELB)', ETag: '#(token.ETag)' }
```

This is just a guess since you say that `token` is a `Map`. But you have not shown the full code.

If things continue to be "too hectic" please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: @nagandlalakshminarayana no use posting here, edit the question or follow the instructions.

Comment: Still getting error 

And cookies = { JSESSIONID: '#(token.JSESSIONID)',  AWSELB: '#(token.AWSELB)', ETag: '#(token.ETag)' } # StepDefs.cookies(String)
      java.lang.RuntimeException: script failed: = { JSESSIONID: '#(token.JSESSIONID)',  AWSELB: '#(token.AWSELB)', ETag: '#(token.ETag)' }
       at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalInNashorn(Script.java:317)
       at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalInNashorn(Script.java:292)
       at com.intuit.karate.Script.eval(Script.java:239)

Comment: @nagandlalakshminarayana see prev comment

Comment: I Have updated my post could please have a look on my code

class BaseAPI {

public static Map apiAuthentication() {

return Map with some values;

}

}

Now could please help us on query. This is how my java class as I declared in above

Comment: Am getting below error message if I use line as you suggested 

Caused by: jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ParserException: <eval>:1:0 Expected an operand but found =
= { JSESSIONID: '#(token.JSESSIONID)',  AWSELB: '#(token.AWSELB)', ETag: '#(token.ETag)' }
^